# Get some desired rows from table by its order

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm working for a page where it shows a tables from database. Let's say I have 100 rows. How to show 21st-30th row?

In the table, there's some fields, not only email, name, and description. So, I used `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

```
for($num=21;$num<=30;$num++){
  $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$num."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

The `$num` shows the desired number but the table itself shows the data from 1st-10th. I want it shows the data from 21st-30th

Comment: have you tried LIMIT  . Ideally it works like SELECT * from MYTABLE LIMIT 21,30  ; This will return rows 21-30

Comment: it should be `LIMIT 20, 10`  (get 10 records beginning with row 21)

Comment: Remove this `$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` inside your loop and consider using if statement to get in between rows.

Comment: @satya no, it won't. Rows in sql have no order other than that defined by an ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

You can already fix your code with sql queries (for faster performance) adding LIMIT 20, 10 (get 10 records beginning with row 21)

but if you have other logic to be applied on your code (as if your displaying dynamic records)

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
for($num=0; $num<=$result->num_rows; $num++) {
    if($num>=21 && $num<=30){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$num."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

other thing you might consider is using foreach

```
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$num = 0;
foreach (range(21, 30) as $row) {
    $num++;

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$num."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['description']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Please, try with sql query, where you defined limit of rows like start from row no to end of row no. I wrote one sql query at bellow:

**Syntax**:

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
LIMIT offset, count;
```

**Example**:

```
 SELECT * from MYTABLE LIMIT 20,10;
```

Answer (score -3):

Two possibilites you can doing this way

**First**

`SELECT * from MYTABLE LIMIT  20, 10`

**Second**

```
// 0,1,2,3....19 19 is record of 20
for($num=19;$num<=29;$num++){

 }
```

Comment: The suggestion of requesting more data from the database than you'll be displaying is inefficient at best.  It's a far better idea to leave the data querying, limiting, and sorting, to the database.